# Intuition behind Penney's game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game): Player A selects a sequence of heads and tails (of length 3 or larger), and shows this sequence to player B. Player B then selects another sequence of heads and tails of the same length. Subsequently, a fair coin is tossed until either player A's or player B's sequence appears as a consecutive subsequence of the coin toss outcomes. The player whose sequence appears first wins.

I understand that we could use law of total probability to calculate the exit probabilities as shown in the first answer [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-solutions-to-Penneys-game-and-what-is-the-explanation). I want to know whether we can (maybe intuitively) know the [best reactive strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game#Analysis_of_the_three-bit_game) without complicated calculation. Otherwise, we have to calculate all the exit probabilities to obtain the best strategy.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for.  For intuition, consider the case where $A$ chooses $TTT$.  Then $B$ chooses $HTT$ knowing that the only possible way $A$ can win is if the coin comes up $TTT$ in the first three tosses.  Thus $B$ wins with probability $\frac 78$.  Other cases are not so extreme.

Comment: That every strategy can be beaten seems at first glance in fact strange , in fact this is why this game is called a paradox. But careful analysis reveals that this is actually the case.

Comment: @lulu I agree with your argument about TTT. I'm looking for similar arguments for other cases.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Conway's algorithm](https://penneyante.weebly.com/conways-algorithm.html).

Comment: Then , try to find out how you counter , say , "HTT"

Comment: Of course, the reason $B$ can always beat $A$'s strategy is the imbalance of knowledge. $B$ picks a strategy knowing $A$'s strategy. $A$ doesn't know $B$'s strategy. The trick for $B$ is to maximize the chance his string will occur before $A$'s string. If the strings couldn't overlap, the best that could be done would be a $50\%$ chance. In thinking about this, I find it helpful to suppose that there is just some infinite sequence of flips that they are searching, rather than ending as soon as someone wins,

Comment: @lulu Is there a reasoning behind this algorithm? I wonder whether for other cases like "HTH" we can give a concise argument like the one you gave for "TTT".

Comment: You can look up Conway's Algorithm online.  But, really, I don't think there is some easy argument out there that people just aren't writing out.  Rather, I think the extreme cases of $TTT, HHH$ are misleadingly obvious.